# ios delegate doesn't fire

Tags: ios, delegates

i try a simple Delegate but the method won't fire. Here is my code:
The view with the protocol and a button which should trigger the delegate:
ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@protocol InitStackDelegate <NSObject>
@required
-(void)initstack:(NSInteger)amount;
@end

@interface ViewController : UIViewController{
    IBOutlet UITextField *amountTextField;
    __unsafe_unretained id<InitStackDelegate> delegate;
}

- (IBAction)init:(id)sender;

@property (nonatomic,assign)id  delegate;

@end
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"


@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize delegate;
- (IBAction)init:(id)sender {
    //send the delegate

    [delegate initstack:[amountTextField.text intValue]];

}
```

AppDelegate.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ViewController.h"
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate,InitStackDelegate> {
}  

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (strong,nonatomic) ViewController *myView;
@end
```

AppDelegate.m

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize window;
@synthesize myView;
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:    (NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    //..... push second controller into navigation stack
    myView.delegate = self;
    return YES;
}
...
#pragma mark Delegate Method
-(void)initstack:(NSInteger)amount{
    NSInteger test;
}

@end
```

When i hit the button i get to (IBAction) init but then the delegate do nothing. I set a breakpoint in AppDelegate.m but it is never reached. Any help?

thx
Mario

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In you App Delegate, when you set myView.delegate=self myView doesn't actually point to anything!
You need to set myView to point to your ViewController.

Use this in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

```
myView = (ViewController *)self.window.rootViewController;
myView.delegate = self;
```